# Outlook add-in not working in 2019 desktop client with Windows Server

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Please help me with the following issue.
I developed an Outlook add-in that works great on the following platforms:

- Mac os
- Windows 10
- Windows 8.1
  However, a client of mine installed it on Windows Server 2016 with Office 2019 and it doesn't seem to work. It stops at the loading screen. I thought that the old Internet Explorer was the reason, but I tried it in the online Outlook website in Internet Explorer and it worked great. The most annoying issue is that whenever I try to open the debugger from Outlook, it won't work / won't open. I don't know why.
  Do you know of any possible reasons that might explain the plugin not working in Outlook but working in the web version? Please help

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that when you launch the addin, you see "loading..." in the taskpane window, and it never disappears? If that is accurate, are you able to get a Fiddler trace/log to help understand what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, you're correct. I thought there are some settings that block javascript execution, but there is the loading view displayed, which suggests that some javascript loads correctly. No, I haven't tried that, but I doubt my client would let me install Fiddler on their machines. Is there any other way to debug it? I tried right-clicking the add-in and selecting the debugging option, but the debug window doesn't show. The strangest thing is that the add-in works perfectly in Outlook for web on their machine.

Comment: From what I can tell, the methods that might fail could be `getAllInternetHeadersAsync` or `loadCustomPropertiesAsync`.

Comment: If the loading screen is the default one from the add-in taskpane, then it is not an indication that some JavaScript has loaded correctly. We display that loading screen while navigating to the SourceLocation / URL of the add-in. This loading screen should go away after a while and show the add-in's page if we are successful, or you will get a yellow warning bar with an error message. Let me know whether you get the error message or not.

Comment: If your add-in has a custom loading screen, and that is what you are seeing, then it means your add-in's page has loaded successfully so you should be able to debug your add-in. Debugging your add-in here depends on your configuration (browsers installed + windows version + office version). More details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins. Consider Windows Server 2016 to be Windows 10. So, if you have a custom loading screen, let me know your configuration and I can provide further assistance.

Comment: If you don't have a custom loading screen, then it will be really helpful if your client can install Fiddler and get a trace while loading the add-in. This will provide us with any HTTP navigation errors which could explain what is going on. There could be firewalls, IE settings (if IE is the underlying browser for add-ins), antivirus software, etc that could be preventing the add-in taskpane from navigating to the URL / SourceLocation. If you don't mind sharing your add-in manifest, feel free to send us a link so that we can try it in house to see if we can discover anything.

Comment: I do have a custom loading screen and it's displayed. This means that **some** javascript (react) is working. The client's configuration is Windows Server 2016 with IE 11 + Office 2019.

Comment: Based on your configuration, Outlook should be using Internet Explorer as the underlying browser. You could try attaching the F12 debugger to see if there any errors in the console. Instructions for attaching the debugger can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10#when-the-add-in-is-running-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thank. I'm waiting for the client. I'll get back to you when I have updates.